# Can't quite get PowerShell pipeline syntax correct

Tags: powershell, syntax

I want to run a simple script which shows all privileged users in Active Directory.  I'm close but I can't quite get the syntax right.  I think the code is pretty self-explanatory:

```bsh
'Domain Admins', 'Administrators', 'Enterprise Admins', 'Schema Admins', 'Server Operators', 'Backup Operators' | 
    ForEach-Object {$groupName = $_ Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive |
    Get-ADUser | Select-Object Name, DisplayName, @{n='GroupName';e={ $groupName }}}
```

In PowerShell ISE, it's underlining Get-ADGroupMember and states, "Unexpected token 'Get-ADGroupMember' in expression or statement."

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

--Jim

Addendum - one more issue that I overlooked but didn't ask about in the question:  Get-ADUser doesn't appear to return the DisplayName property so we must explicitly ask for it:

```
 'Domain Admins', 'Administrators', 'Enterprise Admins', 'Schema Admins', 'Server Operators', 'Backup Operators' |
    ForEach-Object {$groupName = $_; Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties Name, DisplayName |
    Select-Object Name, DisplayName, @{n='GroupName';e={ $groupName }}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve forgotten a semicolon as a statement separator:

```
'Domain Admins', 'Administrators', 'Enterprise Admins', 'Schema Admins', 'Server Operators', 'Backup Operators' | 
    ForEach-Object {$groupName = $_; Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive |
    Get-ADUser | Select-Object Name, DisplayName, @{n='GroupName';e={ $groupName }}}
```

Note carefully the semicolon after `$groupname = $_`. When you are combining multiple statments in a script block and not breaking them with newlines, you need to use a semicolon to separate them.